# Событие на scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать событие, которое запускается когда scroll достигает самого верха в блоке?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  var block = $('.block')
    , console = $('.console');
  $(window).scroll(function(e) {
    var offset = $(window).scrollTop() - block.offset().top;
    if (offset < 0) {
      console.text('Выше блока');
    }
    else if (offset > 0) {
      console.text('Ниже блока');
    }
    else {
      console.text('На блоке');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  height: 1000px;
}

div {
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 16px;
  padding: 16px;
}

.block {
  height: 64px;
  margin-top: 48px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="block">Block</div>
  <span class="console"></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Я конечно не эксперт, но бытует в народе мнение, что лучше юзать таймер вместо обычного события скроллинга
http://joshbroton.com/hooking-up-to-the-window-onscroll-event-without-killing-your-performance/